# Shuffling and Array problems Java

Tags: java

I have a problem in my Java program Black Jack. I can't seem to work out my "this.cards[o++]" as it always goes into ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException. But if I change it into "this.cards[j] OR this.cards[i]" it doesn't get an error but I know its wrong.

Here's the errors for:

```
**this.cards[o++]** 
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 13
        at CardDeck.<init>(CardDeck.java:18)
        at BlackJoker.main(BlackJoker.java:17)

**this.cards[j]**
null
Kc
Qc
8c
null
null

**this.cards[i]**
null
Ac
Ah
null
null
Ad
```

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class CardDeck
{
    private String[] ranks = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
                    "J", "Q", "K", "A" };
    private char[] suits = {'s','h','d','c'};
    private Card[] cards = new Card[13];
    private int currentCard;

    CardDeck()
    {
        Card newCard;
        int o = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<this.suits.length; i++)
        {   
            for(int j=0; j<this.ranks.length; j++)
            {
                this.cards[o++] = new Card(this.ranks[j], this.suits[i]);
            }
        }
        this.shuffle();
    }

    public void testing() //just for testing 
    {
        System.out.println(this.suits[0]);
    }   

    public Card drawNextCard()
    {

        return cards[currentCard++];
    }

    private void shuffle()
    {
        Card[] tmp = new Card[13];
        for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++)
        {
            int index = (int)(Math.random() * (cards.length));

            tmp[index] = cards[i];
            cards[i] = cards[index];
            cards[index] = tmp[i];
        } 
    }
}
```

---

```
public class BlackJoker
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        CardDeck cardDeck = new CardDeck();

        //cardDeck.testing();
        System.out.println(cardDeck.drawNextCard());
        System.out.println(cardDeck.drawNextCard());
        System.out.println(cardDeck.drawNextCard());
        System.out.println(cardDeck.drawNextCard());
        System.out.println(cardDeck.drawNextCard());
        System.out.println(cardDeck.drawNextCard());
        //System.out.println(cardDeck.drawNextCard());
    }
}
```

---

Comment: Notice that "this.cards[j]" gives me a constant 'c' suits then "this.cards[i]" gives me a constant 'A' (ace). Can someone please explain to me what I've done wrong? Thank you so much for any help and advice

Comment: Best to have abstractions Card and Deck, where Deck has a collection of Cards.  You can use the Collections.shuffle() method that's built in.  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/collections_shuffle.htm

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating an array that will only hold 13 cards:

```
private Card[] cards = new Card[13];
```

Try making it 52:

```
private Card[] cards = new Card[52];
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to increasing the card array length ,  In the shuffle function , you are calculating the index using Math.random, that causes ArrayIndexOutbound exception if the index is beyond the card array length. You need to handle this.

Comment: Not a problem. Since `Math.random()` always returns less than 1, `(int)(Math.random() * (cards.length))` will be less than `cards.length`.